# Here I'm going to achive polymorphism but I'll get error

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm trying to achieve polymorphism here but, I'll get error. How can I do that and what changes I need to do here?

```
public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Pleas enter the browser");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String browser=s.next();

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
            FirefoxDriver f=new FirefoxDriver();
            test(f);
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            ChromeDriver c=new ChromeDriver();
            test(c);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid browser");
        }

        public static void test(WebDriver driver)
        {
            String url="https:\\www.gmail.com";
            driver.get(url);

            String title=driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println(title);

            String curl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
            System.out.println(curl);

        }

        driver.close();

    }
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. You're using Java.

Comment: URLs use `/`, not ```\```. `String url="https:\\www.gmail.com";` should be `String url="https://www.gmail.com";`. (If they **did** use backslashes, you would have needed to escape them in the string literal.)

Answer (score 0):

The method driver.close() should be in the method test(). Also, do the classes FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver extend WebDriver?